# Save two graphs in the same png file (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am running the following python function:

```
def plot_keras_history(history, embeddings_dimension, batch_size, version_data_control): #where history =  model.fit()
    """

    :param history: 
    :return: 
    """
    # the history object gives the metrics keys. 
    # we will store the metrics keys that are from the training sesion.
    metrics_names = [key for key in history.history.keys() if not key.startswith('val_')]

    for i, metric in enumerate(metrics_names):

        # getting the training values
        metric_train_values = history.history.get(metric, [])

        # getting the validation values
        metric_val_values = history.history.get("val_{}".format(metric), [])

        # As loss always exists as a metric we use it to find the 
        epochs = range(1, len(metric_train_values) + 1)

        # leaving extra spaces to align with the validation text
        training_text = "   Training {}: {:.5f}".format(metric,
                                                        metric_train_values[-1])
        # metric
        fig1 = plt.gcf()

        plt.figure(i, figsize=(12, 6))

        plt.plot(epochs,
                 metric_train_values,
                 'b',
                 label=training_text)

        # if we validation metric exists, then plot that as well
        if metric_val_values:
            validation_text = "Validation {}: {:.5f}".format(metric,
                                                             metric_val_values[-1])

            plt.plot(epochs,
                     metric_val_values,
                     'g',
                     label=validation_text)

        # add title, xlabel, ylabe, and legend
        plt.title('Model Metric: {}'.format(metric))
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.ylabel(metric.title())
        plt.legend()

        plt.draw()

        fig1.savefig(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'plot_two_figures_{0}_{1}_{2}.png'.format(embeddings_dimension, batch_size, version_data_control)), dpi=100)
        plt.show()
        plt.close()
```

- history argument is the model.fit() result of a neural network
- embeddings_dimension=300
- batch_size=64
- version_data_control (current date)

The above functions print this in the iPyhton cell of Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

But the savefig png file contains only one of them.

[image]

What goes wrong when saving the two graphs, and only one  of them is saved? and in the wrong shape. It should be 12x6.

Changed figure to subplot() as suggested in comments:

```
def plot_keras_history(history, embeddings_dimension, batch_size, version_data_control): #where history =  model.fit()
    """

    :param history: 
    :return: 
    """
    # the history object gives the metrics keys. 
    # we will store the metrics keys that are from the training sesion.
    metrics_names = [key for key in history.history.keys() if not key.startswith('val_')]

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)

    for i, metric in enumerate(metrics_names):

        # getting the training values
        metric_train_values = history.history.get(metric, [])

        # getting the validation values
        metric_val_values = history.history.get("val_{}".format(metric), [])

        # As loss always exists as a metric we use it to find the 
        epochs = range(1, len(metric_train_values) + 1)

        # leaving extra spaces to align with the validation text
        training_text = "   Training {}: {:.5f}".format(metric,
                                                        metric_train_values[-1])
        # metric
        plt.figure(i, figsize=(12, 6))

        axs[i].plot(epochs,
                 metric_train_values,
                 'b',
                 label=training_text)

        # if we validation metric exists, then plot that as well
        if metric_val_values:
            validation_text = "Validation {}: {:.5f}".format(metric,
                                                             metric_val_values[-1])

            axs[i].plot(epochs,
                     metric_val_values,
                     'g',
                     label=validation_text)

            # add title, xlabel, ylabe, and legend
            plt.title('Model Metric: {}'.format(metric))
            plt.xlabel('Epochs')
            plt.ylabel(metric.title())
            plt.legend()

            plt.draw()

            fig.savefig(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model_one\\ploting_training_validation_performance_{0}_{1}_{2}.png'.format(embeddings_dimension, batch_size, version_data_control)), dpi=100)
            plt.show()
            plt.close()
```

, and I get the following error:

[image]

Third change on my code (think I done it):

```
def plot_keras_history(history, embeddings_dimension, batch_size, version_data_control): #where history =  model.fit()
    """

    :param history: 
    :return: 
    """
    # the history object gives the metrics keys. 
    # we will store the metrics keys that are from the training sesion.
    metrics_names = [key for key in history.history.keys() if not key.startswith('val_')]

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)

    for i, metric in enumerate(metrics_names):

        # getting the training values
        metric_train_values = history.history.get(metric, [])

        # getting the validation values
        metric_val_values = history.history.get("val_{}".format(metric), [])

        # As loss always exists as a metric we use it to find the 
        epochs = range(1, len(metric_train_values) + 1)

        # leaving extra spaces to align with the validation text
        training_text = "   Training {}: {:.5f}".format(metric,
                                                        metric_train_values[-1])
        axs[i].plot(epochs,
                 metric_train_values,
                 'b',
                 label=training_text)

        # if we validation metric exists, then plot that as well
        if metric_val_values:
            validation_text = "Validation {}: {:.5f}".format(metric,
                                                             metric_val_values[-1])

            axs[i].plot(epochs,
                     metric_val_values,
                     'g',
                     label=validation_text)

        # add title, xlabel, ylabe, and legend
        plt.title('Model Metric: {}'.format(metric))
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.ylabel(metric.title())
        plt.legend()

    fig.savefig(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model_one\\ploting_training_validation_performance_{0}_{1}_{2}.png'.format(embeddings_dimension, batch_size, version_data_control)), dpi=100)
    plt.show()
    plt.draw()
    plt.close()
```

Stdout:
[image]

Comment: Try using subplot

Comment: Savefig() method only saves the current figure. In your case, you are creating new figure inside for loop. If you want to save mulitple plots in single fille, use subplot instead of figure

Comment: @gnodab check my edit

Comment: @ajaygandhi check also my edit

Comment: remove     plt.figure(i, figsize=(12, 6)) statement from your code and see if it works

Comment: Looks like metric_train_values is empty for loss and accuracy.

Comment: @gnodab metric_train_values is an array with values: [0.09546445444129319, 0.04929035653623106, 0.05900882285728429]

Comment: @ajaygandhi the removal of plt.figure had no impact in the final result. The same as before stdout

Comment: Guys check my final edit, I think I solved the riddle. Although the output is not perfect. Just had to play with the intends of the for loop

Comment: oh man..you had this incorrect indentation.. :(

Comment: @ajaygandhi The good thing is that we figured it out. Thanks for your help :)